# how to show more information in user's profile

Tags: users

by default user's profile in drupal show very little information about users. I can extend that by adding more fields to profiles.
but I want user's profile in such a way that it would be showing all his/her information and some more information like users last 10 posted content, top 10 rated content and most commented content etc.

how can I extend this type of profile view in drupal?
please suggest me, thanks in advance :):)

Comment: I would suggest investigating the Views module for creating blocks of content about the user, eg, your last 10, top 10, commented lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For things like last 10 posted content, I believe you can use contextual filters in Views. With that you can create pages like /user/somebody/posts where Views will show you the last contents of user for example, also I believe you can make a block out of such a view that you can place on profile pages.

Also it may worth for you to check out the Profile2 module, you can create multiple types of profile pages with it for example.

http://drupal.org/project/profile2